# show percentage of home directory usage in root

Tags: bash, shell

I need to make bash script showing the percentage that the home directory occupies in all the root folder.Like this:

```
Root filesystem size: 238G
Home directory size: 125G
Home directory uses 52% of /
```

My try:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(df -h ~ | grep -n '/$' | awk '{print "Root filesystem size:" $2}')
y=$(du -h ~ | tail -1 | awk '{print "Home directory size:" $1}')
echo "$x"
echo "$y"
z=$(echo "$y" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')  
k=$(echo "$x" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
echo "$k / $z * 100" | bc
```

Output:

```
Root filesystem size:31G
Home directory size:8,4G
3
400
```

Comment: Use the program `tree --du ~`

Answer (score 0):

Have to be careful about units with `-h`. Suppose the root size is 500G and the home size is 800M?

Try

```sh
root_size=$( df -k  ~ | awk '$NF == "/" {print $2}' )
home_size=$( du -sk ~ | awk '{print $1}' )

percent=$( echo "scale=2; 100 * $home_size / $root_size" | bc )
```

Or, write the report with

```sh
awk -v root="$root_size" -v home="$home_size" '
    function GB(kb) { return int(kb / 1024 / 1024) }
    BEGIN {
        printf "Root filesystem size: %dG\n", GB(root)
        printf "Home directory size: %dG\n", GB(home)
        printf "Home directory uses %d%% of /\n", int(100 * home / root)
    }
'
```